# Why do allegro crash when blitting? What does these debug reports mean?

Tags: c++, bitmap, allegro

I was programming in c++ using the allegro library in code::blocks. I declared a bitmap, loaded the bitmap and blit the image to test if the bitmap is being drawn into the screen. I compiled this program and the compiler found no errors. When I run the program, the bitmap is not drawn to the screen and allegro crashed. I changed the color depth and made sure that I included things in the code that won't make allegro crash but still no avail. I then run the debug to see if there's something wrong with this program. I get this message:

```
    sigsegv segmentation fault

    #0 10004DDD colorconv_blit_24_to_15() (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\alleg42.dll:??)
    #1 0028FE3C ?? () (??:??)
    #2 1006C3E0 get_uformat() (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\alleg42.dll:??)
```

What does this mean and how can I fix it? Are there any solution to this?
Here's my code:

`$`

```
  #include <allegro.h>

    using namespace std;

int main()
{
allegro_init();
install_keyboard();
set_color_depth(8);
set_gfx_mode(GFX_AUTODETECT_WINDOWED, 640, 480, 0, 0);

BITMAP *link=NULL;
link=load_bitmap("cave.bmp",NULL);

blit(link,screen,0,0,0,0,25,177);

readkey();

destroy_bitmap(link);
allegro_exit();

return 0;
}
END_OF_MAIN()
```

Comment: Why do you think it's OK to not check whether `link` is null and instead post on Stack Overflow?! How are *we* supposed to know whether your image has been loaded?

Comment: I checked it and tried to solve the problem involving "null" but allegro still crashes when bitmap is loaded. I looked all over the forums about why allegro crashes and did what they suggested but still nothing happened and that's why I posted this on Stack Overflow.

Comment: This code works fine if "cave.bmp" exists and is a valid .bmp file. My guess is that your version of cave.bmp does not exist at the path specified (no path is the same as the path of the executable) or it is not valid. The fact that you are not checking whether load_bitmap returns a non-null pointer is an issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!!!

I figured out why allegro crashed. I used Gimp to edit my bitmap before loading it on allegro in code::blocks. For everyone loading their bitmap using the old allegro library, do not use Gimp. Use any other image editing software like paint.net.

UPDATE:
I experimented my bitmap with gimp and it turns out that when I export my image as bitmap, another pop out came showing me the compatibility option and the advanced option. For everyone that uses the allegro library, ignore the top part. You can use Gimp but when you get that pop out after you click "export," click on the plus sign on the left of the compatibility option and that option will drop down and click that check that says "do not write color space information" and then click export. That should work and load fine on allegro.